# C printa diretório do computador, quando função recebe dízima

Tags: c

Estou fazendo uma função em C, que dada uma parte fracionária "frac" de um número na base 10, e uma outra base numérica, retorna a mesma parte fracionária na base desejada.

Para isso, aloco um vetor de char "ret", que armazenarei a parte inteira da multiplicação entre a parte fracionária e a base desejada da conversão. Repito este processo até a variável "frac" ser zerada, ou seja, até houver apenas zeros depois da vírgula.

A função funciona com alguns números fracionários como o **,00244140625** para a **base 16**, por exemplo. Mas ao testar com o número **,076444444 (dizima periódica)** e **base 12**, ela retorna o número correto seguido de um diretório de meu computador.

```
char* dezParaOutraParteFracionaria(double frac, int base)
{
    char *ret = (char*)malloc(MAX*sizeof(char));
    int tamanhoDoNumero = 0;

    while(frac != 0)
    {
        frac = frac * base;
        int parteInteira = (int) frac;

        frac = frac - parteInteira;
        ret[tamanhoDoNumero++] = transformarCharDaBase10(parteInteira);

        printf("%s\n", ret);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Ao verificar os prints feitos, têm-se:

```
0¶ã
0Bã
0B0
0B01
0B011
0B0119
0B0119A
0B0119A7P☺ã
0B0119A7A☺ã
0B0119A7A5ã
0B0119A7A56
0B0119A7A569
0B0119A7A5695
0B0119A7A56953
0B0119A7A569538
0B0119A7A5695385eDrive=C:\Users\user\Onej.ÐÞ;¾
0B0119A7A56953858Drive=C:\Users\user\Onej.ÐÞ;¾
0B0119A7A569538588rive=C:\Users\user\Onej.ÐÞ;¾
0B0119A7A5695385884ive=C:\Users\user\Onej.ÐÞ;¾
0B0119A7A56953858841ve=C:\Users\user\Onej.ÐÞ;¾
0B0119A7A569538588416e=C:\Users\user\Onej.ÐÞ;¾
0B0119A7A569538588416e=C:\Users\user\Onej.ÐÞ;¾
```

Nota-se que a parte **0B0119A7A569538588416** está devidamente convertida para a base 12, mas o **e=C:\Users\user\Onej.ÐÞ;¾** não tem origem conhecida.

O quê pode estar dando errado?

Comment: Você esqueceu de acrescentar o caractere terminador '\0' ao final da string., daí pegar lixo de memória. Coloque: `ret[tamanhoDoNumero] = '\0'` antes do `return`.

Comment: Para o seu teste coloque `ret[tamanhoDoNumero] = '\0';` antes de `printf("%s\n", ret);`. Quando encerrar os testes pode colocar imediatamente antes do return.